# Are there places to spend the night inside San Jose Airport?

Tags: airports, safety, sleeping, sjc

I'm planning one day visit to San Jose, California (morning to evening). I'm arriving at SJC around 11.30pm and hoping to go to the city early morning, the next day. Until that is there a place where I can spend the night inside the airport? Airport lounges which can be booked for 3hrs are closed at midnight.

I checked in sleepinginairports.net, and traveller reviews says, "Dead after 9 pm. No private area to sleep". I just wanted to see if there's anyone who has spent a night there and whether it is safe.

Comment: @chx I don't find your comment helpful if I'm understanding it correctly. If OP is airside, should be as safe as most airports (sleep on your stuff or attach an alarm/lock).

Comment: You will likely be safe, but the airport is not that big and does not have the nooks and remote gates that make sleeping in (the public areas of) an airport less daunting and more comfortable. I am not sure whether airport security will roust you or not; if they do, the neighborhood around SJC is littered with high priced business hotels and seedy, run-down buildings. Walking anywhere from SJC will take a while, and late night transportation is limited to taxis/Lyft/Uber. Good luck.

Comment: @chx Not only is your comment unhelpful, but San Jose is nowhere near any (land) border to the USA.

Comment: You need a backup plan. The San Jose airport is small. The homeless population in San Jose is also pretty significant. Don't expect airport security to have any mercy on you. AirBnBs and Youth Hostels are the cheapest option, but at the time you're coming in, I wouldn't count on them.

Comment: @mkennedy sleepinginairports.net reports that those airside when security closes will be shooed out until security re-opens in the morning.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Because OP didn't mention anything like that, I hoped he or she could stay airside.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are in transit, arriving late and have a flight that departs the following day, you would not be able to spend the night at [San Jose International Airport](https://www.flysanjose.com/)

[San Jose Operations](https://www.flysanjose.com/sites/default/files/Terminal%20Management-Overnight%20Lodging.pdf)

> No person shall sleep in or remain in the Airport terminals overnight for the purpose of lodging, unless: (a) the person has arrived at, is in transit through, or will be departing from the Airport as an airline passenger within twenty-four (24) hours, as evidenced by a valid travel itinerary, ticket, or boarding pass matching the person’s valid identification; or (b) the person is awaiting the arrival of a travel passenger due to arrive within two (2) hours, or within four (4) hours if the passenger’s travel has been delayed, as evidenced by verifiable travel information
>
> **Overnight** 
>   The period each day between the hours of 11 p.m. and 4 a.m., or in the International Arrivals Facility from one hour after the last international flight using that facility to one hour before the first international flight of the day using that Facility.

Safety is under the purview of a special unit of the [San Jose Police Department, the Airport Division](https://www.flysanjose.com/node/1106) whom you might just meet should you decide to spend the night at SJC.

Comment: The statement (a) is "(arrived or departing or both) within 24 hours". If it was only intended for transit passengers, the "or" would be an "and". Therefore, the OP may sleep in the airport, according to this regulation.